# Make Selenium record IDs, not paths

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

When I use the FF plugin **it records the paths of the elements I interact with**. In cases where the DOM is heavily-altered according to the user interaction, **it is more convenient to element IDs**, which are guaranteed not to be affected.

I can record everything and change paths to ID manually, but I was wondering of there is a more clever way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this. In my experience, you can't avoid heavy editing of test scripts for most pages that rely a lot on JS anyways (but that's of course not an answer). I often end up editing every other command (I also have had tests that I had to write in the final exported format from scratch - to allow conditions, loops and such).

Are you really creating so many scripts that this would make a difference? Is so, I guess you could modify the Selenium IDE extension (Firefox extensions are written mostly in JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You could explore the concept of [Selenium UI-Element Locators](http://ttwhy.org/home/blog/2007/05/12/selenium-ui-element-locator/). I haven't used it, but it looks to provide a level of abstraction against varying paths