# Can I tell Selenium to record in DOM mode instead of element ID mode?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have been using Selenium in my DEV environment.  When I go to try some of my recorded tests on my Test environment, I find that the elements have different IDs (they are generated by the web framework).  I can change the test manually to use

```
document.forms[2].elements[3]
```

instead of by id, which looks like this:

```
ellaMform:j_id77
```

I'm looking for a way to tell selenium to record the dom:index value for the controls so that tests will be the same between DEV and TEST.

Similar question on SO points to a plugin but is not exactly what I need:
[Make Selenium record IDs, not paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919390/make-selenium-record-ids-not-paths)

Comment: The accepted way of solving such things is to write the tests manually using the page object pattern. If it is possible for you, consider trying it this way.

Comment: Thanks.  It is no problem doing this manually, but I thought it might save time if I can record in DOM mode.

Comment: This isn't the answer to my question, but my problem was really the auto-generated element IDs.  Once I gave these elements proper IDs in the code, the IDs transfered just fine between dev and test  environments.

Comment: Page objects don't solve mcgyver5's problem, they just centralize it.  He's got a difficult-to-automate application, not badly-written tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE already has locator builders for several DOM styles (e.g., `dom:index`, which matches your model, or `dom:name`, which is less position-oriented).  By default, they are prioritized lower than ID locators, but you can choose which locator you want to use when you record the test.

Comment: "you can choose which locator when I record the test"  That means manually, by using the target dropdown and choosing dom:index right?  And there is not a way to change the default?

Comment: Yes and no.  Yes, you can choose manually.  No, you can change the default, although it isn't trivial.  The order of selection of locators is defined in the last line of LocatorBuilders.js in the IDE code.  You can reset LocatorBuilders.order to choose your own preferences.  See http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/ide/main/src/content/locatorBuilders.js for the current source.

Comment: Someone pointed out recently that the last line of that source file is deliberately intended to be copied to your user-extensions.js file and modified there.  Which makes it a heck of a lot easier.

Comment: It's part of UI for some time now - Options|Options|Locator Builders.